# Is there a way to force user to only use query they are allowed In Teradata

Tags: teradata

I am using the query band so the user can connect through the proxy user to the data pool in Teradata. Proxy users have full access to the table. How can I force the external users to see the selective columns? This is my query:

```
SET QUERY_BAND='PROXYUSER=TheAdmin; PROXYROLE=RoleOne;' FOR TRANSACTION;
SELECT Employee_Id, First_name, Last_Name FROM Project.myTest;
```

This query works, but the problem is if the external user use `SELECT * FROM Project.myTest;`

It returns the whole table. I want that user should not be able to see all the columns.

I don't want to use the view as I have a big DB and there I have to create so many views in each table.

Is there any way to do that? Will be great help and thanks in advance.

Comment: *user should not be able to see all the columns* The common way is granting access rights on a view (limiting the columns returned) instead of the base table

Comment: The external user does not have any access if the user uses only select * from project.myTest;  it through error. The external user has to use the query band. So I cannot revoke or grant access to the external user.  If I give limited access to proxy users it won't help me to get my result.

Comment: How do you know which external user should see which columns? Even if it would be possible to disallow `select *` a user could still simply list all columns.

Comment: Only the trusted user can allow and link, so these users are permanent and granted as trusted without any privileges.  These users are created into their database.  as ExternalUser1 is based under database DB Project and only have access to db project.

Comment: This seems backwards to how ProxyUser / Trusted User are intended to be used. Typically a middle-tier server logs on as Trusted User and uses ProxyUser / ProxyRole to set a specific user / role for authorization of requests. That said, as already noted the normal approach is to give access only via a view layer to limit columns or even objects that can be viewed.